# How to place close button to the end of popup box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have designed a popup box I am placing my popup button to the end of the popup box but when contents has been updated dynamically to the box,the close button is moving out of the box.

Look for my code once

```
#overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

  }
  #box_frame{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
  }
  #box{
     width: 400px;
     padding: 40px;
     height: 200px;
     margin: auto;
     font-size: 14px;
     background:#e8e8e8;
     border: 1px solid #dadada;
     font-family:sans-serif;
   }
   #box button{
     margin-top: 45%;
   }
```

Guys look at my javascript code

```
function open_box(){
      var cont = '<div id="overlay"><div id="box_frame"><div id="box"> '+
              'Select Reviewer:<input type="text" name="name"      onkeyup="load(this.value);" autocomplete="off"/>' +
              '<div id="demo"></div>'+
              '<div id="check"></div>'+
              '<button onclick="javascript:reset_dynamic()">Close</button>'+
              '</div></div></div>';
      document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML=cont;
    }
    function reset_dynamic(){
      document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML='';
    }
```

Guys can you please look at my code and suggest me to place the code button to the end of the popup box.Here "demo" div holds the dynamic content received from ajax response.

Html code:

```
<a href="javascript:open_box()">Select ICR Reviewer</a>
<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

Comment: Would you please add your HTML as well? or simply add a live JSfiddle

Comment: can you make a FIDDLE?

Comment: @SumanthUdupa where is html code.?

Comment: Guys some of html content is inside the javascript cont variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should give the button an id (let's say `close_btn` ) and give it top and right with absolute position:

```
#close_btn {
    position: absolute; 
    top:3px;
    right:3px    
}
```

and you should give the `#box` a relative position :

```
 #box{
     /* this is to make the absolute button
      relative to this parent */
      position: relative; 
   }
```

and i think you don't need the `#box button` rule

Comment: Thank you Majed it worked. Hey why should we have to set position as relative in #box. What happens if we set as absolute for #box.

Comment: if the  position of `#close_btn` is `absolute` it searches for the closest ancestor with `relative` position so for example : if the #box is not relative the relative ancestor would be the whole document so the close button would exist in the top right corner of the whole document. Did you understand ?   sorry for bad English.

Comment: You are awesome Majed. Thank you for your information.

Comment: You're welcome :) you can vote the comment up if it's helpful